# understanding variable assignment in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am noob and trying to understand Python.

For os.walk documentation says that it returns a tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames)

just of understanding I am trying to use it like below

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
file=[]
dir=[]
xroot,dir,file = os.walk('C:\Python27\mycode')
```

But it gives me error like :     xroot,dir,file = os.walk('C:\Python27\mycode')
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

My question is why cant I assign it like above rather then it being part of loop (most example use that)?

Comment: There are multiple files in the directory (seems like two from your error message).  When you use it in a loop, then you get (xroot,dir,file) for each file in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Your code attempts to unpack the generator returned by `os.walk()` into a three-tuple. This is fine, but the problem is that the generator yields only two items, which isn't going to work.

Each item in the generator is a three-tuple itself, which is what your `for` loop is really unpacking each iteration. A more verbose way of writing it would be:

```
for three_tuple in os.walk('C:\Python27\mycode'):
    xroot, dir, file = three_tuple
```

You might find it easier to actually turn that generator into a list:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(list(os.walk('.')))
[('.', ['foo'], ['main.py']),
 ('.\\foo', [], ['test.py', 'test.pyc', '__init__.py', '__init__.pyc'])]
```

As you can see, the result is an iterable (a list) where each element is a three-tuple, which can then be unpacked into a root folder, a list of folders and a list of files.

Answer (score 1):

os.walk returns an iterator. The usual think to do is loop over it

```
for xroot, dir, file in os.walk('C:\Python27\mycode'):
    ...
```

but you can also just use `xroot, dir, file = next(os.walk('C:\Python27\mycode'))` to single step through

Answer (score 1):

`os.walk` does not return `root,dir,file`. it returns a generator object for the programmer to loop through. Quite possibly since a given path might have sub-directories, files etc.

```
>>> import os
>>> xroot,dir,file = os.walk('/tmp/') #this is wrong.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> os.walk('/tmp/')
<generator object walk at 0x109e5c820> #generator object returned, use it
>>> for xroot, dir, file in os.walk('/tmp/'):
...     print xroot, dir, file
... 
/tmp/ ['launched-IqEK']
/tmp/launch-IqbUEK [] ['foo']
/tmp/launch-ldsaxE [] ['bar']
>>>
```

Comment: The SO thread on generators: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/231855#231855